# Which Python versions are officially supported by last SonarPython plugins?

Tags: sonarqube

I need to know to which versions of Python, SonarAnalyzer analyses are restricted to. Is it compatible with Python 2 or 3 or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarPython should be compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3. If you encounter parsing issues, you should report them to the [SonarQube google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube).